# How to pass multiple parameter and its value in string using pass on php path on Arduino uno for dynnamic values?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, arduino-uno

In this image multiple parameter passing static value are passed but the dynamic value are not passed and the Screen monitor of Arduino has been display

> ERROR, flowratereading="" + (byte(flowRate)) + ""

i don't know this syntax is correct or not. i m passing this value in String php path it convert in to byte..

[image]
in this image i don't know multiple value are passed in this syntax or not..
`HTTPPARA` command display error but when i m passing static value so it passed on server side and `HTTPPARA` run display OK message.
[image]